# Using P104-100 GPU on Ubuntu with other Nvidia gpus?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have been experimenting with combining p104-100 (flashed to 8GB) with Rtx 3080 ti's.

On an Asrock Epyc MB they are only recognized if plugged into slots 0-2 (3 furthest from the Epyc cpu.

On an Asus b450-f gaming II (Ryzen) MB I can run upto 4 Nvidia gpus (3 rtx 3080 ti's and 1 gtx 1060 6gb).  Or I can run 2 rtx 3080 ti's and upto 3 p104-100's gpu (mining version of a gtx 1070?).  If I put any 3 Nvidia gpu's online with 1-3 p104-100 gpu's the p104-100 gpus are literally not recognized by "nvidia-smi" or the application I need to use.

I am convinced this is a driver issue.

I have not been able to locate a downloadable linux p104-100 driver to compare it to the standard Ubuntu NVIDIA drivers.  I have tried several NVIDIA drivers all the way back to 470.

Respectfully,
Tom M